# Change button function to a href

Tags: php, html, invision-power-board

I currently have this button on my website, the button changes the theme.
I would like to add this function as a text label somewhere else.

This is the code of the button

```
<li class="ipsMenu_item">
                <form action="//nkips.local/theme/?csrfKey=6d76e45144a958ae2137f7cc1df9ce9b" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="aHR0cDovL25raXBzLmxvY2FsLw==">
                <button type="submit" name="id" value="4" class="ipsButton ipsButton_link ipsButton_link_secondary">Default Dark </button>
                </form>
            </li>
```

But I'm not sure how to change this into a text link.

I've changed the "button" to "a".

Tried it with giving the form an ID and use the onclick function but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Links make GET requests. Your form is making a POST request. 

If you don't like the way a button looks, apply CSS to it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, following seems decent:
button {
  background: none!important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0!important;
  cursor: pointer;
}